# gulp chalk, pass string template through method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a class to handle my notifications. In order to change the text colour a package i'm using accepts the following:

```
const chalk = require('chalk');

chalk`{red This text will be red.}`;
```

However I have now passed this string template into a method instead which then passes it to chalk, however the chalk package isn't parsing the string template. So instead of changing the color the log is just displaying the string passed in.

```
const log = require('./gulp-includes/log');

let test = 'helloworld';
log.all({
    message: `{red This text will be read. ${test}}`
});
```

**gulp-include/log.js**

```
const settings = require('./settings.js');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const log = require('fancy-log');
const notifier = require('node-notifier');

class Log
{
    all(params) {
        this.log(params);
    }
    log(params) {
        log(chalk`${params.message}`);
    }

}
module.exports = new Log();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `chalk` parse string template in `Log` class, you need to simulate the [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) manually --  compose the tag function call yourself.

Fortunately, in this case, expression such as `${test}` in string template has already been evaluated when it appears first time. So the only parameter passed to `chalk` is the half-parsed string, e.g. `'{red This text will be read. helloworld}'` (the value of `${params.message}`), which makes things much easier.

In `Log` class, you can simulate the `chalk` tagged template literal by following method:

```
log(params) {
  let message = params.message;
  let options = [message];
  options.raw = [message];
  log(chalk(options));
}
```

Comment: I was thought I had to do something like this but couldn't for the life of me figure it out from the code nor documentation. Thanks.